# Why does SQL Server Job Agent Alter datetime parameters?

Tags: sql-server

We're encountering a strange issue with SQL Server 2014, whereby agent jobs that utilize datetime parameters are having their values altered every time someone clicks 'Ok' on the job step configuration.

The month and day are being swapped around with datetime parameters being passed in the following format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" . This alteration happens every single time the configure job step box is confirmed out of - regardless if the value of the parameter has been changed by the user or not.

Initially because we're based in the UK - I thought that this might just be a display formatting issue - however upon confirming both my regional settings and that of the server, that does not appear to be the case.

Additionally these phantom alterations are actually taking affect within the job step command line, as verified by checking:

```
select command from [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps]
```

This seemed like a potential bug - brought on by our latest round of patching, but after rolling back those patches - we still have the same issue.

I couldn't find any mention of such a bug anywhere by searching, so perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Don't use the format `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, it's ambigious. Use a non-ambiguious format, such as `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`. My guess, however, would be you have your language set to English, which (stupidly) isn't English, it's American. You, bizarrely, have to pick British if you are English.

Comment: @Larnu you beat me to it. But I wouldn't say that is should be American, the language is English. They should however do a better job of being clear. British English and American English. Kind of like Spanish where there are two dialects. :)

Comment: Yeah - as I mentioned in the question, we've double checked the region and language settings.

Comment: Where did you check the language setting? I bet if you pass a date like `'17/07/2018 10:00:00'` you'll get an error. Either way, using `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` is the key.

Comment: And @SeanLange yeah, it's just me being a little ranty; having the only English option aimed at those that aren't English really frustrates me. :)